# PHP Regular Expression does not match newline with s modifier

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a series of words that span across 2 lines.

Say I have the following text:

```
this is a test
another line
```

My Regular Expression pattern using preg_match:

```
/test.*another/si
```

Test here:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2zj

PHP Pattern Modifiers:
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Everything that I've read points to using the "s" modifier to enable the "." character to match new lines, but I cannot get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: This works for me. Maybe that site you linked to is broken.

Comment: On your test page, if you click the tab for preg_match_all, you can see the pattern matching correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that site is definitely broken.  `preg_match_all` and `preg_replace` work right, but `preg_match` treats each line as a separate input.  Additionally, the cheat-sheet at the bottom is copied verbatim from [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is correct and works fine on my local machine:

```
$input_line = "this is a test
another line";

preg_match("/test.*another/si", $input_line, $output_array);
var_dump($output_array);
```

it produces the following output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "test
another"
}
```

So my guess is that phpliveregex.com is not working properly and giving you false results.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it works. I will confirm the results in my PHP environment later.

Answer (score 3):

Put the modifier in the regex:

```
/(?s)test.*another/i
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Both this and the regex you were using work just fine when I test them. As @byte255 pointed out, there must be something wrong with the site where you were testing it. In fact, if you click on "preg_replace" on the right side in that site and fill in a replacement value, you will see that the regex was actually working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the `s` modifier also known as the dotall modifier forces the dot `.` to also match newlines.

Your regular expression is used correctly and this seems to work for me.

```
$text = <<<DATA
this is a test
another line
DATA;

preg_match('/test.*another/si', $text, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

See working [`demo`](https://eval.in/78774) here.

Output

```
test
another
```